# if block in python not executed with True statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I just started learning python with small scripts. I came across a quiz to determine a list to be symmetric if the first row is the same as the first column,
the second row is the same as the second column and so on.

```
def symmetric(block):
    n = len(block)
    i = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        j = 0
        for j in range(n-1):
            if (block[i][j] != block[j][i]):
                return False
            j +=1
        i +=1
    return True
```

So the result of

```
print symmetric([["cat", "dog", "fish"],
                ["dog", "dog", "dog"],
                ["fish","fish","cat"]])
```

should be False.

However, this code always return True, and in debugger I can see `block[i][j] != block[j][i]` returns True but the if block is not executed. Is there anything wrong with the comparison or the if block is not correctly composed?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Comment: Third line `i = 0` does not make sense! Same for fifth line.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason why it fails is because you should write `range(n)` instead of `range(n-1)` (the upperbound is *exclusive*). Like:

```
def symmetric(block):
    n = len(block)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if block[i][j] != block[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
```

Nevertheless, there are several weird things about this function:

- you initialize `i = 0` and `j = 0`. That is not necessary: in Python, the `for` loop will *declare* the variable for you;
- you perform increments/decrements on `i` and `j`, this is again not necessary. A `for` loop enumerates over the iterable/generator and assigns each value to `i` and `j`;
- usually one does not write parenthesis for `if` statements.

Furthermore you can actually make this code more elegant using a two-liner with the `all(..)` builtin function:

```
def symmetric(block):
    n = len(block)
    return all(block[i][j] == block[j][i] for i in range(n) for j in range(n))
```

This is a more *declarative* and more *explicit* style of writing code. Since here the code is almost self-explaining: "*return whether all `block[i][j] == block[j][i]` for `i` in `range(n)` and for `j` in `range(n)`*"

Finally like [@Błotosmętek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518042/if-block-in-python-not-executed-with-true-statement/44518118#comment76028971_44518118) says in their comment, you do not have to check `block[2][0] == block[0][2]` if you have already checked `block[0][2] == block[2][0]`. So you can improve performance (about half) by writing:

```
def symmetric(block):
    n = len(block)
    return all(block[i][j] == block[j][i] for i in range(n) for j in range(i))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I didn't understand if upper bound is exclusive in range(), why no error is thrown? The buildin function is very elegant. Can't believe the code can be so concise......

Comment: @missmissyou: if you write `range(3)` it will emit `0`, `1` and `2`. So the `3` is **not included** in the output. Since the length of your "matrix" is 3, you thus will range over all valid indices 0, 1 and 2. That' is why the bound is exclusive.

Comment: One minor improvement - it is enough to go through a triangle matrix, as the elements on diagonal are always equal to themselves: `return all(block[i][j] == block[j][i] for i in range(1,n) for j in range(i-1))`

Comment: @Błotosmętek: shouldn't it be `range(i)`? Mind that the upperbound is exclusive :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am very well aware of it, and yes, you're right, I first wanted to write it a bit differently, changed the idea and left this bit uncorrected.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `range(n)` rather than `range(n-1)`; sequences generated by `range` do not include the upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Changing to range(n-1) does the fix, however in the debugger I can see block[0][2] and block[2][0] are reached...

Answer (score 1):

```
def symmetric(block):
    n = len(block)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print i, j
            if (block[i][j] != block[j][i]):
                return False
    return True

print symmetric([["cat", "dog", "fish"],
                ["dog", "dog", "dog"],
                ["fish","fish","cat"]])
```

In python you don't have to declare or increment the variable used for looping, python "for-loop" is intelligent enough to do it for us.

You also have to study how the range function works in python, range() can be called in three ways,

range(N-number of times to loop): range will return a list of N integers starting from 0 to N-1.

range(S-start position, N-end position): In this case range will return a list of (N-S) integers starting from S to N-1.

range(S-start position, N-end position, K-steps): here range will return a list of (N-S)/K integers starting from S to N-1 with an interval of K.

In your case when you said `range(n-1)` your loop was iterating only on indices 0,1 skipping index 2, no wonder you were getting True every time.